# getting textbox value from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have an `TextBox` named `pass` in `Form1` that I need to get the value of in `form2`. I tried this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public string GetPass() {
        return pass.Text; 
    }
}

public partial class form2 : Form {
    //... 
    MessageBox.Show(new Form1().GetPass());
}
```

The above code returns an empty string, why?

Comment: This code will always return empty string (or a constant string if the textbox text property is set by default on form1) as you are creating new instance of Form1 in form2 and then trying to access the GetPass(). You need to pass the reference of Form1 object to form2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not showing your actual code as evidenced by the syntax errors etc. - the only logical explanation for your problem is that you are not passing the reference to `Form1` correctly to `Form2`, but create a new form instead - that new form would have the empty textbox.

To further help you, please show how you pass the reference to your Form1 in your actual code.

**Edit:**

Is see your edit now and above is exactly the problem. You have to pass a Form1 instance to form2 instead of creating a new one, i.e.:

```
public partial class form2 : Form 
{
  private Form1 form1;

  public form2(Form1 otherForm)
  {
     form1 = otherForm;
  }

  public void Foo()
  {
     MessageBox.Show(form1.GetPass());
  }
}
```

Comment: Works if `form1` is created before `form2`.

Comment: While this works, I'd say use properties instead of methods here. You're simply returning a value here.

Answer (score 4):

Define one string variable as Public in declaration section 
for ex. we have a form with name "frmOne"

public string strVar = string.Empty;

Now, assign the value of TextBox of "frmOne" to that variable from where you are getting the value of Textbox.

for ex.

```
strVar = Textbox1.Text.ToString();
```

Now in another form say "frmTwo", you will get access the value of that textbox of "frmOne" something like that (where you want to get the value) :

```
frmOne frm = new frmOne();
string strValue = frm.strVar;
```

So, finally strValue local variable of frmTwo contains the value of Textbox of frmOne.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a new instance of `Form1` each time you call `GetPass()`.

You need to get the instance of the opened `form1` one way or another, and call `GetPass` on it:

```
form1.GetPass();
```

If there is no specifics on the order of creation of `form1` and `form2`, you can use the following to get the instance of `form1`:

```
foreach (Form openedForm in Application.OpenForms) {
    if (openedForm.GetType() == Form1) {
        MessageBox.Show(openedForm.GetPass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a NEW form1 where the textbox is likely to be blank, and calling GetPass() on that empty form. You need an instance of the already-opened form1 where the textbox might have a value.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning empty because you're creating a new instance of the form. Assuming that `Form1` is already open somewhere, you need to retrieve the existing instance of `Form1` and pull the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can write this :

```
 public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        internal Form2 F2=new form2();

            private void CommandBarButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(f2.TextBox1.Text);

    }

}
```